# Python - Iterate through list of list strings

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of strings, and I would like to iterate through the 2nd index in each sublist. But, instead of assessing each string it is assessing each character of each string... here is what i mean:

Current Code:

```
fruit = [['bananna',"apple",'grape'],['ham',"sammy",'canada']]    
for l in range(len(fruit)):  
    for i in fruit[l][1]:    
        print i
```

Desired output:
apple
sammy

Current output:
a
p
p
l
e
s
a
m
m
y

Really I would like to take some action with each string. Search for that string in another list but right now it appears to be assessing every character of the strings I want to look at instead of the string as a whole... not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
>>> for l in fruit:
...     print(l[1])
... 
apple
sammy
```

It works because the `for` statement allows to [iterate over the elements of a list](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) (no index needed).

**Original problem:**

```
1 fruit = [['bananna',"apple",'grape'],['ham',"sammy",'canada']]    
2 for l in range(len(fruit)):  
3    for i in fruit[l][1]:    
4        print i
```

The problem is in line 3:

- `fruit[l]` is one of the sub-lists (e.g. `['banana', 'apple', 'grape']`).
- `fruit[l][1]` is the second item in this list (`'apple'`).
- `for i in fruit[l][1]` [iterates over the string](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) (`'apple'`), which picks up each character.

Comment: Strings are iterable in Python. What's happening is that in for i in fruit[l][1], you are iterating over every character in the second string in every sub-list.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @JasonMc92

Comment: Thank you, @CarlosMermingas, for the edit. Very well done!

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing:

```
for l in range(len(fruit)): #you have the inner_loops in each iteration  

    for i in fruit[l][1]: # You already have what you want in fruit[l[1]

        #you are now getting charcter by character from each value
```

What should do:

Just skip a loop. And it is more pythonic to iterate by value, not by index.

```
fruit = [['bananna',"apple",'grape'],['ham',"sammy",'canada']]    
for l in fruit:      
        print l[1]
```